# Why does top margin does not get applied after clearing the float?

Tags: html, css, css-float

In following, `.p1` is cleared from earlier floating box and applied a top margin to it expecting it would shift further below from the top edge of viewport, then what is achieved with `clear`, however the `margin-top` does not seem to work if `clear` is used, if `clear` is removed, it works. Why?

**HTML**

```
<span style="float:right;width:30%;">
  content content content content content content content content...
</span>

<p class="p1">content content content content...</p>

<p>content content content content...</p>
```

**CSS**

```
span, p {
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: #ede;
    padding: 10px; }

 .p1{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 200px;
   }
```

Can anybody explain why this `margin-top` does not work on `.p1`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a `<div>` (in my case named `.clear`) before the `.p1`. Like:

```
<span style="float:right;width:30%;">
  content content content content content content content content...
</span>

<div class="clear"></div>

<p class="p1">content content content content...</p>

<p>content content content content...</p>
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
span, p {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #ede;
  padding: 10px;
}

.p1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<span style="float:right;width:30%;">
  content content content content content content content content...
</span>

<div class="clear"></div>

<p class="p1">content content content content...</p>

<p>content content content content...</p>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I could have done it, I wanna know the reason why it stays sticking below the floated  block even if a very large margin-top value is set say, `margin-top:400px`.

Comment: @Saurav Rastogi: If that's the case, then the clearing element's margin should start from the bottom edge of the float. But it doesn't. So your reasoning is wrong.

Comment: This is because the margins between a floated box (`span` & `.p1`) and any other box are collapsed.

Comment: Did you seriously delete your comment citing the spec and then make up a statement that's just a direct contradiction of the statement from the spec?

Comment: You should never add an element just to clear a float. There are far better ways to do that.

Comment: @Rob Yes I know we can use `display` property as well but this is just an alternative.

Comment: But a bad one that should not be done.

Comment: @Rob Can you tell me the reason why this is a bad way to solve the purpose in this question's context?

Comment: Adding elements that don't add content or value of any kind only clutters up the DOM and are useless and pointless in the face of properly using CSS which does the same thing.

Comment: As with Muhammad's answer below, this makes no attempt to actually answer the question ("why does the margin not get applied?"), only to offer a workaround.